# Is it possible to change TextOptions of FormattedText in c# using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to draw a FormattedText with different rendering options. When we create for example a Label we can set its TextOptions.TextFormattingMode(Ideal/Display) and TextOptions.TextHintingMode(Auto/AntiAliasing/ClearType/Grey Scale).

I want to set hinting mode and formatting mode on my FormattedText. I think TextFormattingMode can be passed as a constructor argument but what about TextHintingMode? Is it possible to set it?

Answer (score 2):

Both `TextRenderingMode` and `TextHintingMode` can only be set at the `Visual` level. So no, you won't be able to apply it to a specific `FormattedText`, only the entire control it's rendered in.

Answer (score 0):

Both `TextRenderingMode`, `TextHintingMode`, `TextFormatingMode` (and many more) can be set in code, just like that:

```
TextOptions.SetTextHintingMode(myControl, TextHintingMode.Fixed);
```

I use it after creating the control, before adding it to the visual tree, works just fine. I don't know if setting this value for a control already in the visual tree is enough to invalidate the visual (and force a redraw).